# Cannot delete SharePoint site collection using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, content-database

To cut it short, the site collection still remains in Central Admin while the content database is deleted. I used powershell, but I get `cannot open database "db" after requested by the login. Login failed.`

Login is just fine, but the database is not there and I cannot do a restore of the deleted site.

So, I can I clean this faulty site collection without having the content database?
I have taken a test content database from my dev machine and deployed to the other farm. Now, I would like to attach this content database with the existing site collection which does not have a content database. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

When a content Database deleted from SQL without 1st removing from SharePoint then all the sites become orphans.

In this case, go to Central Admin > Application management > Manage Content Database...On this page select the web App from top right then you will see the content DB, click on it and on next page remove it.

Once the DB will gone from Central admin, it will refresh the Config DB and remove the site collection from Central admin.

Comment: the database is not there. It is not visible to in Central Admin and not in SQL  server.

Comment: Then it is cached some where? Two things try to reset IIS or clear the config cache on servers...